# Why do all commercial aircraft have carpets?

Tags: aircraft-design, airline-operations, airlines

When flying I noticed that all the commercial aircraft I have been on use carpets as a floor covering. But why? If you fly in an older aircraft it looks worn out and it is susceptible to stains etc. Why do they not use one of the hard flooring options like linoleum?

Comment: I'd guess that carpet patterns on planes, like upholstery on other forms of transport (e.g. train seats) are likely designed to make staining *less* obvious. Here's a good BBC article about train seats, which have some similar constraints: http://www.bbc.com/autos/story/20160804-why-are-trains-seats-so-hideous

Comment: Comfort and vibe; carpeting is the last remaining thing that separates a plane from a school bus with wings. A cheap passenger-train style hard floor on a plane would suck the last remaining bits of [hope](https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/2b/93/69/2b9369c2b468449f2f26ce5ede5ae19f.jpg) out of the whole experience of flying somewhere, fully immersing passengers in soulless despair. *shudder*

Comment: I once took a domestic Chinese flight where the floor was grooved rubber matting. Definitely felt cheap and "school bus with wings"!

Comment: @jonrsharpe holy cow at the "skin-crawling video" linked from article - and we sit on those things....

Comment: Hey, it's just because -be honest, who doesn't like a flying carpet?

Answer (score 119, accepted):

- helps prevent slips and falls
- contains spills (your spilt soda won't ruin your neighbors bag)
- more easily removed and replaced
- helps reduce cabin noise

Comment: I'd *guess* it's less poisonous in a cabin fire, too.

Comment: @ceejayoz That would depend on a lot of things like the material of the carpet, the glue used and what type of hard flooring you are comparing it to.

Comment: You may also consider weight

Comment: The second bullet point is also even more important than usual on an airplane, as they tend to spend a rather significant amount of time with the floor not perpendicular to the gravity vector (meaning spilled things would spread faster than normal and not necessarily just to your neighbor.)

Comment: @reirab in that case it also has a non-slip effect -- even a plastic bag with any weight in it doesn't slide around in normal operations on carpet, but on a shiny surface everyone would end up with bags sliding into their feet on acceleration.

Comment: I doubt the "more easily removed". That doesn't depend on the walking surface, only on the backing surface and that can be made identical.

Comment: @reirab actually, the only times in flight that gravity isn't pointing straight down, normal to the floor, would be during takeoff and landing. Banked turns merely increase the acceleration felt downwards, they don't change its direction at all.

Comment: @grkvlt Well, actual gravity always points toward (a close approximation of) the center of Earth during flight, though you're right that the normal force during turns points more-or-less towards the floor during turns. However, most aircraft fly with a slight nose-up attitude (and the exact angle changes during flight as fuel is burned off and the weight changes.) And, of course, during climb and descent, the angle between the floor and the gravity vector is even more exaggerated. Also, if a turn isn't quite coordinated, then there will be also be apparent lateral forces.

Answer (score 34):

### The answer: High heels!

The [local pressure of high heels](http://hypertextbook.com/facts/2003/JackGreen.shtml) would punch a hole in the aluminium or composite flooring, and a carpet is the lightest way to distribute the loads such that the local pressure from high heels can be tolerated. **This** is the real reason.

From [Aircraft Structures Summary](http://www.aerostudents.com/files/aircraftStructures/aircraftStructuresFullVersion.pdf)

> On the floor of the fuselage also very high localized loads can occur,
>   especially from small-heeled shoes. Therefore floors need a strong
>   upper surface to withstand high local stresses.

Other reasons are improved noise absorption and damping of vibrations. Nobody likes it when the floor panels start to resonate when excited by  some engine or pump frequency.

With composite panels now in widespread use for cabin interiors, manufacturing flaws need to be covered, and carpets serve this purpose well. From [Compositesworld.com](http://www.compositesworld.com/articles/advanced-materials-for-aircraft-interiors):

> Because sandwich panel facesheets are very thin, core print-through is
>   common. Further, pinholes can form as phenolic resins outgas during
>   reaction and cure. Therefore, panels visible to passengers typically
>   are surfaced with some type of decorative material to cover surface
>   flaws. Floor panels can be painted or covered with flame-retardant
>   carpet.

Comment: skydiving in a Cessna 206 taught me that it's totally fine when bits of the floor and interior resonate, but I can see why it wouldn't be great on commercial. I'd never thought about heels on a plane, who does that!!

Comment: Last week I flew on the Airbus A350 demo aircraft which has section of the flooring made out of fake wood. They said it was new for the A350, looked really cool, Qatar Airways has it in their A350 at the entry:
http://www.nycaviation.com/2016/01/photo-tour-onboard-qatar-airways-a350-900xwb/39773

So there must be other reasons for using high heals than local pressure alone.

Comment: @Brilsmurfffje: An airline which places style over weight savings puts laminate flooring in their aircraft and you suspect other reasons for using carpet. I guess I have a bridge which I can sell you for a reasonable price …

Comment: I’ve spent hours reading your answers (you should write a book) and this is the most surprising!

Answer (score 12):

Could you also imagine the difficulty of holding the trolley during turbulence or anything else? It would roll down and run someone over!

I also saw a [Quora post](https://www.quora.com/Why-is-carpet-the-predominant-flooring-choice-in-airplanes) where someone had pointed out it's also flame retardant, which is a good point.

Comfort is important too, not to mention another place to put advertising on some planes

Comment: so you do away with trolleys. Who needs meal and drinks service in a run down city bus style airliner anyway :)

Comment: Flammability is a rule https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/14/appendix-F_to_part_25

Comment: "The average burn length may not exceed 8 inches, and the average flame time after removal of the flame source may not exceed 15 seconds. Drippings from the test specimen may not continue to flame for more than an average of 5 seconds after falling." that's actually quite interesting

Comment: It's significantly easier to print advertising on a hard floor than a carpet, so that's not a contributing factor.

Comment: I wouldn't say significantly, given that there are plenty of solutions that all work the same way for both hard and soft floors. I'm not saying replace the entire carpet each time obviously..

Answer (score 6):

**Carpet is more pleasant**

Aside from the practial reasons Greg already mentioned, most if not all people, will consider a carpet as a more pleasant material than *ugly* linolum. The fact that you have to replace a carpet after some years, counts also for most the interior in a plane (seats, board-entertainment, cover panels and so on). Furthermore a lot of people take their shoes of during long flights and a carpet feels in this situation a lot more comfortable.
In the *good old days* TWA rolled out a red carpet for their passengers at the check-in desk :)

Comment: The mental image of an endless array of people each enjoying the feel of the same patch of carpet on their shoeless feet is not a pleasant one, in my opinion. :)

Comment: I take regulary showers!